# Bootstrap3 nesting column conflict

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make nested columns using bootstrap3, Logically everything is set well, but I can see that the rules for a specific size overwrite another size, for instance I'm applying some rules when the screen size is medium but it affects the large size, also the text appears on top of the images, I don't know where is the problem.
another question is there a way for the image to be resized ( scaled ) automatically?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap 1</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body{ text-align: center; }
        img{ height:150px; width: 150px; margin: 0 auto; display: block; }
        @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px){
            div{text-align: left;}
            h1{margin-top: 0;}

        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <section class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-6 col-xs- offset-3  col-lg-offset-0 ">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-3">
                        <img src="images/4.svg" class="img-circle" alt="1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <h1>hello world</h1>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                        consequat.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
                </div>
            </section>

            <section class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3  col-lg-offset-0 ">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-3">
                        <img src="images/1.svg" class="img-circle" alt="1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <h1>hello world</h1>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                        tempor 
                        </p>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </section>

            <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div><!-- as the elements have been broken at some break points-->
            <section class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3  col-lg-offset-0 ">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-3">
                        <img src="images/2.svg" class="img-circle" alt="1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <h1>hello world</h1>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                        consequat.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>

            <section class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3  col-lg-offset-0 ">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-3">
                        <img src="images/3.svg" class="img-circle" alt="1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <h1>hello world</h1>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                        consequat.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>

            <section class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3  col-lg-offset-0">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-3">
                        <img src="images/1.svg" class="img-circle" alt="1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <h1>hello world</h1>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                        consequat.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>

            <section class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3  col-lg-offset-0 ">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-3">
                        <img src="images/2.svg" class="img-circle" alt="1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <h1>hello world</h1>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                        consequat.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>

        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

the result should be the following:
- 6 columns at the large screen
- full-width columns at a small screen
- 3 columns at a medium screen

Answer (score 0):

---

Way for the image to be resized automatically use:

```
background-size: cover;
```

---

For styling rule use `!important` like

```
display: block !important;
```

Comment: yes thank you Naveen, but this works for a background image and in my case, I'm using an image within a section to be on the left side and the description be on the right side and whenever I resize the window, the image scales, any ideas?